# Ghidra Load Linux Headers

Tags: reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer a linux kernel module (kernel version 4.19).
Ghidra does recognize correctly all function names such as: `open`, `misc_register` etc, but it cannot determinate their exact signatures.

Let's take as an example function copy_from_user with signature:

```
unsigned long copy_from_user (void *to, const void __user *from, unsigned long n);
```

and here's how Ghidra sees it:

```
undefined _copy_from_user (void)
```

I believe that it won't be the last kernel module for me to reverse engineer and so I would like to learn how to load all missing kernel structures to the program.

Moreover I am aware that I can edit the function signature by hand, but I would then need to add plenty of structures by hand as well (such as struct file) and this would be very ineffective.

#### What I've tried so far

(I'm super new to Ghidra and if you know better way to load linux kernel headers, please just share.)

I've downloaded headers from debian repository:

```
$ wget linux-headers-4.19.0-6-common_4.19.67-2+deb10u2_all.deb .
$ ls
linux-headers-4.19.0-6-common_4.19.67-2+deb10u2_all.deb  usr
$ ls /usr/src/
linux-headers-4.19.0-6-common
```

I extracted and then tried to load them using File>>Parse C Source option by specifying the path to the extracted folder..

[image]

and got an error. What can I do to make Ghidra aware of the correct function signatures?

### Update:

As MechMK1 has pointed out I have provided a directory instead of header files. I've corrected my mistake and this time I've just copied the whole content of all files into all_headers.h

```
$ cat `find . | grep .h` > all_headers.h
$ cat all_headers.h | wc -c
29824650
```

And I've provided all_headers.h to get parsed. This time there was no error, but Ghidra has only added around 20 defines and no function signatures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error explains it pretty well. Ghidra expected a C file, not a directory.

Comment: This doesn't look to be about security or even reverse engineering, but about an error in this specific tool. And the error seems self-explanatory, at that. (You didn't specify files to parse ...)

Comment: This question is not about an error, but about the general technique of importing linux kernel headers to Ghidra.

Comment: Still, because this is about a specific tool, and one only tangential to security, it's off-topic. Have you looked at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, you are right!